# Tracking page views without server access

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web application that is installed on 28 different servers that are very difficult to access. These apps are all mapped to a single base URL that I manage.

Is there a way to track views of a specific page in the app without installing tracking code on all 28 servers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say, "These apps are all mapped to a single base URL that I manage."?

Comment: @BaileyS app1.myurl.com, app2.myurl.com, etc.

Comment: Short of using your control of DNS records to proxy every request to each app server to insert the tracking code (extremely impractical/unreliable), owning the domain does little to help you with GA tracking.  You really need to actually include the code snippet on all of the pages.  How do you update the app?  Surely there must be a way.

Comment: Got it. What if I don't use GA at all? For example, could I set up a DNS record to ping a server each time specific url is accessed?

Comment: That would be highly dependent on how/where your DNS records are hosted.  Most cloud based providers do not provide any sort of request logs.  Some DNS servers will allow you to log all queries which might be helpful.  Realize that DNS responses are often cached by other servers, so one log entry might represent 1 or 10,000 users (ie. if a query is cached on 8.8.8.8).  Setting a very low TTL might help if the webapp has minuscule traffic and DNS performance doesn't matter.